# Android M: Intercept when a user turn off a run-time permission from App settings

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Can we detect when the user turns off a dangerous permission from the app setting or intercept it so we can show him a pop up at the moment?

Comment: No, what you can do is check for permissions everytime you need them to perform some operation. At that point you can show a dialog explaining the user that your app needs such privileges to achieve some task.

Comment: you have to implement runtime permission on every scenario where it is needed. For example, everytime you would save some stuff to sd card, request the permission before, so you can get sure that your app works correctly. If permission is not allowed by the user, stop doing relevant work and inform the user WHY the app needs that permission.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your process simply is terminated.